# OSX High Sierra Dock on left AND right

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-high-sierra

I like having the Dock auto hidden on the left side. But when connecting a second screen I would like to have it on the **left** side of the **left** screen and on the **right** side of the **right** screen.

I don't think this is currently possible from house. Any suggestions (including external tools) to configure this?

Maybe changing it like [this](https://applehelpwriter.com/2014/10/27/change-the-dock-position/) depending on which monitor the mouse is?

Thanks,
Kim

Answer (score 0):

So I wrote an AppleScript which does exactly this. More on Github:
https://github.com/wuestkamp/osx_dock_multi_monitor